# I want to split a matrix equation in LaTeX

Tags: beamer, align, matrices, split

[image: Matrix Equation]

I want to write these matrix equation in latex in Beamer platform using this code but I am getting error.

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{bmatrix}
\left[\matrix{\mathdot{\omega_{t\Delta}}\cr \mathdot{\omega_{\Delta}} \cr \mathdot{\theta_{tw\Delta}}} \! \right] \! \! = \! \! &\, \! \left[\! \matrix{{1 \over 2H_{t}} \! \left[ \! {k_{p}K_{Cp}v_{0}^{2} \over \omega_{t0}} - {k_{p}v_{0}^{3}C_{p0} \over \omega_{t0}^{2}} \! \right]\! & 0 & { - k_{s} \over 2H_{t}}\cr 0 & { - k_{p}\omega_{0} \over H_{g}} & {k_{s} \over 2H_{g} }\cr 1 & - 1 & 0} \! \right] \! \left[ \! \matrix{\omega_{t\Delta}\cr \omega_{\Delta}\cr \theta_{tw\Delta}} \right]\cr & + \left[\matrix{{k_{p}v_{0}^{2} (3C_{p0} - K_{Cp}\lambda_{\rm REF}) \over 2H_{t}\omega_{t0}} & {k_{p}K_{\beta}v_{0}^{3}K_{b} \over 2H_{t}\omega_{t0}}\cr 0 & {K_{f} \over 2H_{g}\omega_{0}}\cr 0 & 0} \right] \left[ \matrix{v_{\Delta}\cr f_{\Delta}} \right]&\hbox{(19)}\cr P_{e\Delta} = &\, 3k_{P}\omega_{0}^{2} \omega_{\Delta} - K_{f}f_{\Delta}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: why are you using the `bmatrix` environment? Sounds like you want to use `multilne` isntead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the plain TeX syntax `\matrix{...}` which is not allowed when `amsmath` is used (and it's necessary for `bmatrix`).

It's not the only problem, though.

1. `\mathdot` should be `\dot` and just over the variable name
2. `\over` is deprecated in LaTeX
3. You need `align` and `split`
4. Manual numbering of equations is done with `\tag`
5. In order to get more generous spacing in matrices with fractions, you can locally set `\arraystretch` to 1.2

```
\documentclass[tbtags]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \dot{\omega}_{t\Delta} \\ \dot{\omega}_{\Delta} \\ \dot{\theta}_{tw\Delta}
\end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{1}{2H_{t}} \Bigl[
    \frac{k_{p}K_{Cp}v_{0}^{2}}{\omega_{t0}} - 
    \frac{k_{p}v_{0}^{3}C_{p0}}{\omega_{t0}^{2}}
  \Bigr] & 0 & \frac{-k_{s}}{2H_{t}}
  \\
  0 & \frac{-k_{p}\omega_{0}}{H_{g}} & \frac{k_{s}}{2H_{g}}\\
  1 & - 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \omega_{t\Delta}\\ \omega_{\Delta}\\ \theta_{tw\Delta}
\end{bmatrix}
\\
&\quad + 
\begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{k_{p}v_{0}^{2} (3C_{p0} - K_{Cp}\lambda_{\mathrm{REF}})}{2H_{t}\omega_{t0}}
    & \frac{k_{p}K_{\beta}v_{0}^{3}K_{b}}{2H_{t}\omega_{t0}}\\
  0 & \frac{K_{f}}{2H_{g}\omega_{0}}\\
  0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  v_{\Delta}\\ f_{\Delta}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{split}
\tag{19}
\\
  P_{e\Delta} &= 3k_{P}\omega_{0}^{2} \omega_{\Delta} - K_{f}f_{\Delta}
\tag{20}
\end{align}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]